# LayeredGraphPlot with Tooltip

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

In the `Tooltip` I want to change `LinkHand` for an image of a medium sized clock, but I get an error.

In the following image I show how I do the programming.

[image]

Code:

```
relacion = {"MY TOOLS BOX" -> "SET OF ICONS", 
   "MY TOOLS BOX" -> "UTILITY", "SET OF ICONS" -> "Search", 
   "SET OF ICONS" -> "Apps", 
   "Apps" -> 
    MouseAppearance[Tooltip["Alarm Clock", "AAA"], "LinkHand"], 
   "Apps" -> "Converter Units", "Apps" -> "Webcam", 
   "Apps" -> "ScheduledTask", "Search" -> "Open File", 
   "Search" -> "Firefox", "UTILITY" -> "Examples.nb", 
   "UTILITY" -> "Participación"};
LayeredGraphPlot[relacion, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexLabeling -> True,  ImageSize -> 1200, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> (Text[
     Framed[Style[#2, 22, Black, Bold], FrameStyle -> Thick, 
      Background -> LightYellow], #1] &)]
```

Comment: I don't get an error message, but I (on v 11.3) don't get to see the clock either. "LinkHand" and "NoOp" do work indeed. Outside of the `LayeredGraphPlot` your `MouseAppearance` with clock works as intended. Looks like a bug to me that could be reported to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: I am confused by this. I am on MMA 11.2, Win7-64. I tried your code a first time, and it gave no error, but also did not show both the changed pointer and the tooltip. I even wrote an answer thinking that your `VertexRenderingFunction` was at fault, but then I retried your code, and now it works! Something is fishy though...

Comment: Yes, I think there must be an error. I use v.11.3.